# Having trouble understanding regex modifiers in perl to convert to python

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm having trouble converting these perl regex to python, I've converted simpler ones before. I don't really understand the modifiers /s and /is, I know that /g is global.

I also don't know what the first one exactly does. The second removes a specific li tag with a message in html files.

```perl
# First
$data =~ s/\]\((\/uploads\/.*?\.pdf)\)/\]\(ref\/\/\/docs$1\)/g;

# Second
$data =~ s/<li>.*?https:\/\/www\.example\.com.*?<\/li>/$test/is;
```

```py
# What I think might work in python
data = re.sub('<li>.*?https:\/\/www\.example\.com.*?<\/li>/' + test, data, 1)
```

Comment: `/i` and `/s` do the same thing as they do in python, i.e. ignore case (`/i`) and let dot match everything including new line (`/s`). `/is` just means that both `/i` and `/s` gets applied.

Comment: Oh okay, I think i figured out the second one using that but I still don't particularly understand the first. Do you have an idea on how to convert it?

Comment: [As documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) global substitution like you have in the first example should be done with `re.sub` and `count=0`.

Comment: Steffen Ulrich, I found out that the first one just adds "ref:///docs to the beginning of what it finds with the regex search. How would I do that in python? Also, to use modifiers in the second such as s and i, s, how do I do that in python?

Comment: *"Also, to use modifiers in the second such as s and i, s, how do I do that in python.."* - use `(?is)regex`  in python is is same as /regex/is in Perl.

Comment: *"I found out that the first one just adds "ref:///docs to the beginning of what it finds with the regex search. How would I do that in python?"* - please read the documentation to `re.sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First regex does nothing but appends `ref///docs` to the beginning. 
**Explanation**:

```
/\]\((\/uploads\/.*?\.pdf)\)/g
```

- `\]` matches the character "]"
- `\(` matches the character "("

  1st Capturing Group (/uploads/.*?.pdf)
- `\/` matches the character "/"
- `uploads` matches the characters "uploads" (case sensitive)
- `\/` matches the character "/"
- `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `\.` matches the character ".
- `pdf` matches the characters pdf (case sensitive)
- `\)` matches the character )

**Global pattern flags**

- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

**Consider the example**:

`test_str = "](/uploads/something.pdf)"`

perl:

```
my $test_str = "](/uploads/something.pdf)";
$test_str =~ s/\]\((\/uploads\/.*?\.pdf)\)/\]\(ref\/\/\/docs$1\)/g;
```

python:

```
test_str = "](/uploads/something.pdf)"
test_str = re.sub(r"\]\((\/uploads\/.*?\.pdf)\)", r"](ref///docs\1)", test_str)
```

Output of printing `test_str` after substitution:

```
](ref///docs/uploads/something.pdf)
```

I don't know what you really want to do in second regex, but the perl regex says to replace any URL of example.com to any variable `$test`. Lets play around:

perl:

```
my $test = "test";
my $data = "<li>list 1 https://www.example.com/site </li>";
$data =~ s/<li>.*?https:\/\/www\.example\.com.*?<\/li>/$test/is;
```

python:

```
data = "<li>list 1 https://www.example.com/site </li>";
test = "test"
data = re.sub(r"<li>.*?https:\/\/www\.example\.com.*?<\/li>", test, data, re.S|re.I)
```

Output of printing `data` after substitution:

```
test
```

**Modifiers**:

- `i` means ignore case (case insensitive search)
- `s` means dot will now match any character (including newline)

Comment: Thanks so much for all the info! I didn't see this until now but I fixed the first one like 3 days ago and ended up just using BeautifulSoup for the second one. The second one replaces that specific <li> tag with $test which is a custom <li> tag. I looped through all li tags in the file and if it's text contained a specific text, I changed it with a different tag. Should I change it to the regex, would it be more efficient or does it not matter?

Comment: Regex is most often heavy on system, we should avoid it (complex regexes).